# Object texture 1 pixel lines on some sides of model

Tags: texturing, image

I want to add textures to a model (which is mostly cube-shaped) **without the use of UV maps**.

I use object mapping which looks good on the bottom of the cube but on the sides, it seems like a 1px border of the texture is used and stretched upwards along the sides. Moving a node makes the texture projection even stranger.

[image: Texture lines on sides of cube]

It is as if the texture's colors were 3d-printed and the 3d model is being cut out of the texture "block".

[image: Texturing changes with normal of face]

How can I make the textures be "printed" on the surfaces, so it doesn't matter which way they are facing, **without using UV maps**.

Comment: I'd appreciate the reason for downvoting of course.

Comment: I've no idea who downvoted, but you could try to use *Cube* mapping in the texture **Mapping** rollout if you'd like to avoid unwrapping. However this may be not the best way.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Mr Zak Cube mapping is the correct way, have in mind however that Blender's OpenGL rendering engine does not support displaying of automatic cube mapped generated texture coordinates directly in the viewport or game engine, it always displays as a 2D mapped texture stretched on the sides.

When you render your images however, it will display correctly.

If you plan on using the OpenGL render or the game engine you will have to unwrap as generated or automatic cube texture coordinates are not currently supported.

For cycles render engine you can use object or generated texture coordinates, but again there is no support for previewing on the viewport, except for basic UV Mapped textures